# The possibility of linking two perceptual modalities in a coherent way

Tags: philosophy-of-language, perception, semiotics

I am reading the book of Roy Harris "Rethinking writing" and see his arguments in favor of autonomity of writing from speech.

> There could be no complete isomorphism between any system of visible marks and any system of sounds for a quite fundamental reason already mentioned above; namely, the incommensurability of the sensory modalities involved.
>
> ...the basis on which visual configurations are identified and distinguished has no phonetic counterpart at all.

I will not agree: there can definitely be established some kind of morphism between visual and audible just because we have systems of visualization, illustrations of sound waves. I am sure there are systematic relations between signifieds and signifiers in a vast majority of cases, which bears out the possibility of establishing iconic (diagrammic) - in Peirce's sense - signs - what exactly is needed in the case of a system of sounds and a system of written figures.

So, do those visualization means tackle the task? Are the two perceptual modalities really incommesurable?